# Highcharts: heatmaps - incorrect colors on reversed colorAxis

Tags: highcharts

When using color stops with reversed coloraxis, colors of the heatmap are not rendered correctly, but in the opposite order - see http://jsfiddle.net/CpL6F/

```
    colorAxis: {
        reversed: false,
        min: 0,
        stops: [
            [0, '#FF0000'],
            [0.25, '#FFAF00'],
            [0.5, '#7FFF7F'],
            [0.75, '#007FFF'],
            [1, '#0000FF']
        ]
    }
```

Low values should correspond to blue, but they are shown in red.

For non-reversed colorAxis, everything works fine.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: It's bug in Highcharts, reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3190).

Comment: This issue has already been fixed on [Highcharts v4.1.4](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3190#ref-commit-5da8f0d).

Answer (score 0):

This issue has already been fixed on [Highcharts v4.1.4](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3190#ref-commit-5da8f0d).